# send message to single device using Firebase cloud with Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send messages to single devices using their token from a Java application. I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK. Below is what I have

```
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = null;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("google-services.json");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    FirebaseOptions options = null;
    try {
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://MYPROJECTID.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    String registrationToken = "MYDEVICETOKEN";

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    Message message = Message.builder().putData("time", "2:45").setToken(registrationToken)
            .build();

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    String response = null;
    try {
        response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Response is a message ID string.
    System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
```

But I get the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' field not specified.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that your `google-services.json` file contains invalid data. `GoogleCredentials` class expects your file to have a `type` property, but it's not there.

Brief googling gave me [this](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/141#issuecomment-216181122) post regarding very similar problem. It says:

> From the API Manager, just create select "Create credentials" >
>   "Service Account key" and generate a new key for the Service 
>   that is associated to your Google Play account.

Answer (score 2):

Click on Generate new private key button.
[image: console snapshot]